# Keyword not supported: 'authentication' error for azure integrated connection

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-authentication

Getting Keyword not supported: 'authentication' error while trying to connect an azure DB through 'Active Directory Integrated' option in .NET core 2.1 project.

Note: I am using EF core to connect the Data source.

Comment: can you add you code snippet for better clarity...

Comment: This is my local.settings connection string "ConnectionString": "Data Source=tcp:********.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=********;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated", and when creating context with EF core i'm getting the error in below line of code
            WriteLogMessage($"Database Connection set to {Database.GetDbConnection().Database} and data source {Database.GetDbConnection().Database}")

Comment: @suresh could you post the error message and full call stack. it's diffcult to help without sufficient information

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TL;DR**
As called out by @Aamir Mulla in the comments, this has officially been added since [Version 2.0.0](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/2c2f100d8ab9a1f6ee8c048a260d77e6a738e1e7/release-notes/2.0/2.0.0.md#added)

---

**UPDATE - 16/08/2019**
Active Directory Password Authentication has now been added for .NET Core in [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 1.0.19221.1-Preview`](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/release-notes/1.0/1.0.19221.1-Preview.md)

---

Unfortunately, the `authentication` keyword is not yet fully supported in .NET Core. Here is an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8807) which discusses this.

But .NET Core 2.2 has added some support for this use case as mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8807#issuecomment-441830487). The basic idea is to get the access token by [any means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token) (ADAL, REST, etc.) and set `SqlConnection.AccessToken` to it.

As for using this with EF Core, there's a good discussion about this in this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11928) and in particular the [comment by mgolois](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11928#issuecomment-455312550) provides a simple implementation to the solution that [cbriaball mentions](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11928#issuecomment-387420827) in the thread.

Here is the same for reference

> Note that this sample is using the [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/) library

```
// DB Context Class
public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
  public SampleDbContext(DbContextOptions<TeamsDbContext> options) : base(options)
  {
    var conn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)this.Database.GetDbConnection();
    conn.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
  }
}

// Startup.cs
services.AddDbContext<SampleDbContext>(options =>
{
  options.UseSqlServer(<Connection String>);
});
```

The connection string would be something like this
`Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<db_name>;`

Comment: Any update on when 'Authentication' will be supported?

Comment: ...not to be confused with "System.Data.SqlClient".

Comment: Thank you sir!
Setting 'conn.AccessToken' in DBContext is exactly what I needed.

Comment: UPDATE: Officially added since 2.0.0 https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/2c2f100d8ab9a1f6ee8c048a260d77e6a738e1e7/release-notes/2.0/2.0.0.md#added

Answer (score 43):

If you're still having the issue, make sure you have
`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package installed, not `System.Data.SqlClient`. They both contain `SqlConnection` class, switching the package for the first one fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Can confirm this solved my issue.

Comment: This was it exactly - if you're using .NET Core 6, this is probably your solution

Answer (score 3):

As of today 7/18/2022 , I am still getting the issue from Azure when trying to use it through ManagedIdentity.

The microsoft doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cefcore%2Cdotnetcore

to use managed identity we need to use the connection string in this format!

"Server=tcp:.database.windows.net;Authentication=Active Directory Default; Database=;"

But looks like Azure is not liking it!
[image]

However, adding the access token helped!

```
var connectionString =
                "Server=tcp:yourazuresqlservername.database.windows.net; Database=yourazuresqldbname;"; 
var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
//And then
 con.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;

 con.Open();
  //Do sql tasks
 con.Close();
```

Comment: Make sure you use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and not `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: You can add "Authentication=Active Directory Default;" to your connection string instead