# can not connect Azure SQL with Azure AD user in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have a powershell script used to query Azure SQL database with Azure AD user. I can run the poweshell script on my local machine. But when I host the powershell script on Azure function, I always get the error : keyword not supported: 'authentication'

My script

```
$Username = “”
$Password = “”
$Port = 1433

$cxnString = "Server=tcp:$serverName,$Port;Database=$databaseName;UID=$UserName;PWD=$Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=Active Directory Password"

$query = ''

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $cxnString - Query $query
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyword not supported: 'authentication' error for azure integrated connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023686/keyword-not-supported-authentication-error-for-azure-integrated-connection)

Comment: is your Username fully qualified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, now we can not implement it with PowerShell in Azure Function. Now we can implement it with .Net Core Function. We need to package `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

For example

```
 SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            string userName = "<>";
            string password = "<>";
            string server = "<>.database.windows.net";
            string database = "test";
            builder.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:" + server + ",1433;Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Authentication=Active Directory Password;User ID=" + userName + ";Password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM StarWars";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            log.LogInformation(reader.GetString(2));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]