# How to connect to the Azure DB if your connection string is not supporting the authentication keyword

Tags: sql, .net, azure-active-directory

My connection string contains an authentication keyword whose value is Active Directory Password but when I am using it then my code is throwing an error. Is there any other way to establish the connection?

[image]

Comment: Did you get the connection string from portal and follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/design-first-database-csharp-tutorial#c-program-example?

Comment: Which version did you use? For some version, AAD is not support. Please ref here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet

Comment: Thanks for your reply Leon. I am using the .Net SDK core version 3.1.101.

Comment: And yea I have taken the string from the portal only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I searched and find that, keyword "authentication" is not yet fully supported in .NET for now.

This extension is built on .Net Core, which didn't have support for Azure Active Directory authentication at all until recent prerelease versions. That is why the keyword error above is shown.

For more details, you could ref the Microsoft engineer's answer here:

1. [Keyword not supported: 'authentication' error for azure integrated connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023686/keyword-not-supported-authentication-error-for-azure-integrated-connection)
2. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/1159

HTH.