# Connecting to a function app to Azure SQL with managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect my function app to Azure SQL using the instructions found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity

I built the function app using VS2022 using .NET 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio?tabs=in-process

Then I created the DB function using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup

I hardcoded the Sql Authentication username and password and that works but when I change the sql_connection string to this: "Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Database=testdb" (and changing the server and db), I get the following error: "Keyword not supported: 'authentication'."

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this. it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023686/keyword-not-supported-authentication-error-for-azure-integrated-connection

Comment: please once go through this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73025347/18043699) for similar problem.

Comment: @thebernardlim sorry for the delay, but sifting through this link resolved my issue. Many thanks for your help.